# Why doesn't Oracle have all_functions table?

Tags: sql, oracle

we have all_tables,all_procedures,all_triggers but not all_functions.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, there is no need for this. From [ALL_PROCEDURES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm#i1585339):

> ALL_PROCEDURES
>
> ALL_PROCEDURES lists **all functions and procedures**, along with associated properties.

```
SELECT object_name, object_type FROM USER_PROCEDURES
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b04fde37df8cefbf668bc307d4c23e7)**

---

Please note that some languages do not distinguish between procedure and function.

Or like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` you get combined info in [`ROUTINES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table.